# Dynamically call C++ class members for all objects in a vector

Tags: c++, oop, c++11

I have a problem I'm trying to solve with a very non-obvious solution (at least to me). Suppose I have a simple class

```
class Foo {
  private:
    int x, y, z;
  public:
    Foo(int x, int y, int z) : x(x), y(y), z(z) {}
}
```

properties x, y, z also have public getters and setters.

I have a class encapsulating a vector of Foo, `Item`, which initializes them and gives them default values, etc...

Now `Store` is being modified by a third class `Processor`. Essentially the behavior I'm trying to implement is the following:

- `Processor` has a vector of std::function which contains pointers to different members of `Store` such as `ChangeItemSpecs()` or `ChangeItemSourcing()`. It's a list that is looped through and called repeatedly.
- `Processor` checks `Store` after the functions are called, if they are "good" changes. For example, if the total value of the store has increased, or if the store has a lower operating cost. I may have different processors that analyze a model containing pointers to different members of `Store` that do different things. Or perhaps the same things, but just runs a different analysis.
- If the change is not favorable, `Processor` should "roll back" the changes made. **and this is where I am struggling with the design**

Initially I was thinking of somehow getting pointers and indices of the items that are going to be changed, and have `Processor` make copies of them, since `Item` is pretty much just a step above a POD class. If proposed change is not favorable, `Processor` would replace the modified `Item` with the original `Item` copy. But this is wildly inefficient because I have a very large data set.

My problem boils down to this: I want a generic way to store prior information about an `Item` (or bunch of items) in a way that I can change the specific properties back if `Processor` doesn't like the change.

I thought about making an object called `Change` where `Store` can register members that process and roll back a change, then having `Processor` store an array of `Change` objects. Change would have a member called "proposeChange" and "Rollback" change (is there a different paradigm where it would be appropriate to have "acceptchange" ?). Then `Processor` would simply loop through each `Change` item per iteration and do its thing. But this doesn't really solve the problem of managing the information for rollback. Just another abstraction...

Any help is greatly appreciated. Am I approaching this problem incorrectly? Is there a different way of looking at it? How can I design it? I don't really need code, unless it employs some esoteric features of C++, or is very advanced - I just need guidance on how to design a system that's efficient.

**Other comments:**

- Performance is key. There are potentially hundreds of thousands if not more `Items` in each `Store. Hence why I think the copy method I suggested in the first place is too much of a performance hit.
- It should stand up to simple parallelization. Which means that storing state information in Model is probably not a good idea (or is it?). I would like to very simply parallelize the iterations in `Processor`. If I'm overlooking something and this becomes very complicated, then we can forget about this for now.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Roll back makes me feel like you should check out the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_pattern

Comment: Could you elaborate on the relation between `Store` and `Item`? I can see some bits like *"different members of Store such as `ChangeItemSpecs()` or `ChangeItemSourcing()`"* and *"There are potentially hundreds of thousands if not more Items in each `Store`"* but I don't see any explicit description of that relation.

Comment: A store contains a properties of its own, in addition to a vector containing many many `Item` objects. A store also have public members that give back aggregate statistics on Items, or provide access to a specific item or items. Items can also be added or removed from the store. Is there anything else that's pertinent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your approach using `Change` objects that record the changes a modification causes is a good direction.

Actually, this is a very functional approach and as a rule of thumb, parallel likes functional.  I don't think that I fully understand your model but let's assume for simplicity that we only have a list of items and can insert or remove items.  Then it boils down to two simple transformations.

- *f*<sub>ins</sub>(*L*, *i*, *X*) — inserts item *X* at position *i* into list *L*
- *f*<sub>del</sub>(*L*, *i*) — removes the item at position *i* from list *L*

As you can see, *f*<sub>ins</sub><sup>−1</sup> = *f*<sub>del</sub> and vice versa.

Using [*composition*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition) we can build arbitrarily complicated changes.  Also note that generally (*f*<sub>1</sub> ∘ *f*<sub>2</sub>)<sup>−1</sup> = *f*<sub>2</sub><sup>−1</sup>  ∘  *f*<sub>1</sub><sup>−1</sup>.

So once you have identified the elementary operations that constitute a change to your model and defined the inverse operation for each, a complex change can be composed out of them and rolled back by applying the inverse operations in reverse order.

If you like design patterns, this is the *Command* pattern.  The nice thing about the transformation objects is that they are generally very simple and can be serialized and stored away if needed.

If you want to try multiple changes in parallel, you can even take this a step further by using the *Decorator* pattern.  Instead of actually applying your changes directly to the model, you make a decorated model that applies the changes each time an interface function is called.  So for example, if you decorate the model with a transformation that inserts item *X* at position *i* in *L*, the decorator only stores this information.  Then, if a request for the *j*-th element is made, the decorator checks whether *j* < *i* and if so, simply forwards to the existing model.  Otherwise, if *j* > *i*, it forwards to the model asking for element *j* – 1.  Finally, if *j* = *i*, it returns its own element *X*.  Each decorator only needs to store the transformations, not the entire model.  And you can stack decorators together to enable sharing of identical changes.  If you find out that the change was for the worse, simply dispose of the decorator and nobody will ever notice.  If you really like a change, it can be applied to the model but in this case, all other decorators will be invalidated so it shouldn't happen too often in a concurrent application.

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking for! Thank you... In implementing this, I definitely am facing some technical challenges - but I think that's a separate issue entirely. However, the command pattern is a nigh perfect match for what I'm trying to do.